# Heroku Redis max memory error

Tags: heroku, redis, sidekiq

My production environment has started constantly throwing this error:

```
Error fetching message: ERR Error running script (call to f_0ab965f5b2899a2dec38dec41fff8c97f7a33ee9): @user_script:56: @user_script: 56: -OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
```

I am using the `Heroku Redis` addon with a worker dyno running `Sidekiq`.

Both Redis and the Worker Dyno have plenty of memory right now and the logs don't show them running out.

What is causing this error to be thrown and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a job that required more memory than I had available in order to run.

Answer (score 0):

Run "config get maxmemory" on your redis server. Maybe that config is limiting the amount of memory Redis is using.

Comment: Not sure how to run that command on Heorku - but on their dashboard I can see the most ive used in the past 24 hours is 16MB out of 25MB limit.